# Ubuntu 14.04 host cannot mount NTFS disks with VT-d enabled in bios

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, ntfs, linux-kvm, vt-d

I've been setting up an Ubuntu server with KVM, as documented at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation.  Once I started virt-manager and set up my 2nd video card for pass-thru, it informed me that VT-d was not enabled.  I exited virt-manager without proceeding with the Windows install, restarted, enabled VT-d in the bios, and henceforth 2 of my NTFS-formatted storage drives cannot be detected at boot time displaying the message,

`"disk drive /media/storagedrive is not ready yet or not present. Continue to wait, or press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery"`

When I press M, I get to a root shell prompt, and issuing "fdisk -l" indeed shows the drives to be absent.  Another storage drive, ext4-formatted, always mounts as usual.  If I disable VT-d and reboot, there are no mounting problems whatsoever.  So what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have mentioned that I'm using the original Big Bang XPower motherboard.  Apparently, there is an issue where the VT-d feature causes a conflict with the SATA 3 controller, and disks on the SATA 3 ports can no longer be detected.  I discovered this after disconnecting the drives and moving them to different ports.  Disabling VT-d re-enables the ports.